# Python multiprocessing pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle '_subprocess_handle'

Tags: python, multithreading

Hello there I am a beginner at python 2.7 multithreading and I am trying to make a system that allows the user to add images to a list and that list of images will then be processed on different threads. And when the process finishes processing the image it looks at if any new images were added to the list and if there are it would spawn a new process. However, right now I am having a problem where it is saying that I cannot pickle because this is a class. I have tried looking into copy_reg and I do not understand how I would use it or how to implement it so could someone try to show me how. Also, could someone tell me some tips to improve this?

Many thanks!

This is my class:

```
class Populator(object):
    def __init__(self, image_processing_method, max_number_of_processes):
        self.image_processing_method = image_processing_method
        self.max_number_of_processes = max_number_of_processes

        self.running_processes = {}
        self.queue = []
        self.index = 0

    def add_image(self, image):
        if len(self.running_processes) == self.max_number_of_processes:
            self.queue.append(image)

        else:
            self._add_process(image)

    def _add_process(self, image):
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=self._run, args=(image, self.index))
        self.running_processes[self.index] = process
        self.index += 1
        process.start()
        # process.join()

    def _run(self, image, process_index):
        self.image_processing_method(image)

        # self.running_processes[process_index].join()
        del self.running_processes[process_index]

        if not len(self.queue) == 0:
            next_image = self.queue.pop()

            self._add_process(next_image)


def foo(x):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    populator = Populator(foo, 4)

    for i in range(1000):
        populator.add_image(i)
```

This is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/****/Documents/GitHub/********/********/********.py", line 95, in <module>
    populator.add_image(i)
  File "C:/Users/****/Documents/GitHub/********/********/********.py", line 65, in add_image
    self._add_process(image)
  File "C:/Users/****/Documents/GitHub/********/********/********.py", line 71, in _add_process
    process.start()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 130, in start
    self._popen = Popen(self)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 277, in __init__
    dump(process_obj, to_child, HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 199, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 67, in dispatcher
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 401, in save_reduce
    save(args)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 554, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 313, in save
    (t.__name__, obj))
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle '_subprocess_handle' object: <_subprocess_handle object at 0x04C150F0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 381, in main
    self = load(from_parent)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 1384, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 864, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 886, in load_eof
    raise EOFError
EOFError
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle '\_subprocess\_handle' object: <\_subprocess\_han dle object at 0x00AAAAAAA>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32003657/pickle-picklingerror-cant-pickle-subprocess-handle-object-subprocess-han)

Comment: @internet_user I did look at that link as well however I did not understand how he changed his code to make it work and why that makes it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiprocess coding is tricky; I'd recommend trying to learn about multiprocessing with something much simpler, first. For one thing, read about [multiprocessing.Pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) - it manages a lot of the work you're trying to do here.

As for your immediate problem - well, there are a number of problems here.

- You're trying to use a `list` for your queue; that won't work. Lists aren't shared between processes. You need to use a [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues) instead. (But this is also something that `multiprocessing.Pool` manages for you.)
- As for the actual problem you're running into - you're using an instance method (`self._run`) as your multiprocessing target. I think it's probably possible to do this, but it's certainyl not simple. You should just make `image_processing_method` your process target:

  ```
  process = multiprocessing.Process(
      target=self.image_processing_method, args=(image,))
  ```

  This looks similar, but `self.image_processing_method` is just a function, not an instance method, so it will work as the target.
- Finally, you're trying to have your subprocesses manage adding new work to the queue - that should happen in the main process. (It may not need to happen at all - if you use `multiprocessing.Pool`.)

Comment: Thank you for your input. One thing that I am confused about is how would I move on to the next image using Pool and Queue? What I do not want is having to have an empty loop running to see if  there are entries.

Comment: If you use Pool, it simply calls your worker function whenever necessary - when there is work to do and not too many processes already running (which you set when constructing the pool).  You don't have to manage it.

Comment: Oh so instead of having a separate queue for the images that need to be processed I would just pass them all in Pool and it would (given it's processes parameter) run the processes all at once, running the next one process waiting in an internal queue of the Pool class?

Comment: That sounds about right! I'd recommend checking out the example in the [`multiprocessing.Pool` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool)

Comment: Thank you very much! You really helped me there I have been stuck on this for hours!